# how to connect Azure SQL DW using Managed Identity using azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-synapse, azure-managed-identity

I've tried using the Azure function code to connect to SQL server and was successfully able to connect. However, when I try using the same code for SQL DW (dedicated SQL Pool), I am getting the below error.

Can anyone please help me with this ? I'm unable to figure out what is the issue here.

> Exception while executing function: Synapse_Connectivity -> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) -> The parameter is incorrect",
>
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Synapse_Connectivity
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The parameter is incorrect
>
> End of inner exception
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity,SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,SqlCredential credential,Object providerInfo,String newPassword,SecureString newSecurePassword,Boolean redirectedUserInstance,SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions,SessionData reconnectSessionData,DbConnectionPool pool,String accessToken,Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling,SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>
> > 
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject,UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout,Boolean
> allowCreate,Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)\r\n   at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory
> connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions)\r\n   at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at
> async FunctionApp_WBA_QA.Synapse_Connectivity.Run(HttpRequestMessage
> req,TraceWriter log)\r\n   at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n
> at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor
> function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.FunctionRequestInvoker.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken,WebScriptHostManager
> scriptHostManager,WebHookReceiverManager webHookReceiverManager)\r\n
> at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(??)\r\n
> at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
> controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async
> System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

```
at
```

}

My configs are :

"CFG_SQLDB_server": "XXXX.database.windows.net",
"CFG_SQLDB_database": "XXXXqadb",
"SYNAPSE_SQL_server": "XXXXsqlsrv.database.windows.net",
"SYNAPSE_SQL_database": "XXXXqa-sqldw"

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp_SQL
{
    public static class Synapse_Connectivity
    {
        [FunctionName("Synapse_Connectivity")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string synapse_db_server = GetEnvironmentVariable("SYNAPSE_SQLDB_server");
            string synapse_db_name = GetEnvironmentVariable("SYNAPSE_SQLDB_database");

            string ResourceId = "https://database.windows.net/";

            string sqlConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source=tcp:{0},1433;Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", synapse_db_server, synapse_db_name);

            log.Info($"sqlConnectionString : {sqlConnectionString}");

            /* Getting the Token FOR SQL */
            var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            string accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(ResourceId);
            log.Info($"AccessToken : {accessToken}");

            log.Info("Connecting to database.");

            var myObj = "";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                conn.AccessToken = accessToken;
                conn.Open();

                var statement = $"select * from ext.test for json path";
                log.Info($"{statement}");

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            log.Info($"{reader.GetString(0)}");
                            myObj = reader.GetString(0);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

        }

        public static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
        {
            return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, I'm assuming this is a "Dedicated SQL Pool (formerly SQL DW)" and not a Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool, which would have some different answers.

I don't guarantee that any of this will work, but a few items come to mind.

1. Make sure the SQL Server Firewall is configured to allow Azure Services:

[image]

2. In the SQL Server IAM, you ***may*** need to grant Reader RBAC role to the Azure Function's Managed Identity:

[image]

[NOTE: this example has SQL Security Manager, your role would most likely be Reader]

3. I think you'll need to add a USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER to the Database for the Azure Function and grant it *db_datareader* permissions:

   CREATE USER [your_azure_function] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db-datareader' [your_azure_function];

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-managed-identities-sql#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%20navigate%20to%20your%20Azure,REST%20API%20and%20a%20managed%20identity%20connection%20string.) is for connecting a different service, but I think the general rules probably apply.

Comment: Thank you Joel and yes, you are right. I was looking for Dedicated SQL Pool (formerly SQL DW). I've followed all the above steps and still getting the error. Hence I was a little doubtful on the approach. Especially when I've followed the same steps to access Database and was successful.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to tell you, but it seems there must be something wrong with the connection string at runtime.